# How to use compact variable in laravel blade?

Tags: php, laravel

i am trying to get order detail. when i am define a loop in blade and compact a variable inside the loop that is `@foreach($orders as $order)` order undefine

```
@foreach($orders as $order)
<tr>
    <td >{{$order->User['fullname']}}</td>
    <td >{{$order->User['email']}}</td>
    <td >{{$order->User['address']}}</td>
    <td >{{$order->User['user_contact']}}</td>
    <td >{{$order->total_ammount}}</td>
    <td >
        <button type="button" id="{{$order->id}}"  class="btn btn-warning my-2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">--}}
                    Order Details
        </button>
    </td>
    <td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: plz post your controller action's code

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're passing `$orders` variable as a compact from your `Controller` code, and that user is a relation you defined on your order model, which has `user_id` property (or similar foreign key). If that's the case, you can access user's data with something like this:

```
@foreach($orders as $order)
    <tr>
        <td >{{$order->user->fullname}}</td>
        <td >{{$order->user->email}}</td>
        <td >{{$order->user->address}}</td>
        <td >{{$order->user->user_contact}}</td>
        <td >{{$order->total_ammount}}</td>
        <td >
            <button type="button" id="{{$order->id}}"  class="btn btn-warning my-2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">--}}
                        Order Details
            </button>
        </td>
        <td>
@endforeach
```

If that's not the case, you need to do following steps:

Add foreign key to your `Order` class (in your orders table), something like `user_id`. After that, define `order->user` relationship on your Order model:

```
public function user(){
   return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id');
}
```

And you will be able display user data using an example I gave you above.